# Postgres UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

I'm using postgres and rails to develop an app. When I run `rake db:migrate` I got the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "recipients" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "chat_rooms" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_564b3640ba"
FOREIGN KEY ("recipient_id")
  REFERENCES "recipients" ("id")
```

My migration file is:

```
class AddRecipientToChatRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :chat_rooms, :recipient, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end

  def drop
    remove_reference :chat_rooms, :recipient, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

My schema is:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170430135119) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "chat_rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.integer  "created_id"
    t.index ["created_id"], name: "index_chat_rooms_on_created_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["recipient_id"], name: "index_chat_rooms_on_recipient_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["sender_id"], name: "index_chat_rooms_on_sender_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["title"], name: "index_chat_rooms_on_title", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "chat_room_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.index ["chat_room_id"], name: "index_messages_on_chat_room_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_messages_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_users_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

end
```

I have read about this issue and I understand that postgresql is looking for a **recipients** table but in fact recipients are taken from **users** table, in other words recipients is an alias of users. I have specified that in my model with:

```
belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'
```

I have some an idea on how to fix the issue but not sure if it's going to maintain ***referencial integrity***:

- Create an integer field named `recipients_id` and then add a foreign key with: `add_foreign_key :chat_rooms, :users, column: :recipients_id, primary_key: :user_id`

Any suggestion is welcome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your migration then to this. You can also skip the `def drop` part.

```
def change 
  add_column :chat_rooms, :recipient_id, :integer, index: true
  add_foreign_key :chat_rooms, :users, column: :recipient_id
end
```